# US Foreign-Owned LLC that owes no income tax - Do I have to file anything?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company

I am a nonresident alien, looking to start a Single-Member LLC that does Web Design in the US, with no US office and performing services exclusively from my home country. My understanding is that this would be a disregarded entity, and is taxed on US-Sourced Income, which this is not (because the Source is where services are performed, as it says in Publication 519).

So what do I file? Technically I don't think I have to file anything. But then, what will the IRS think about all this money moving through? How can I let them know about my situation? Should I file 1040NR even if I owe no income tax?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to do business "outside the country", why establish an LLC "here" at all?  You should establish a business in your home country if you desire business organization for sequestering liabilities or something.  With or without a business organization, you will presumably be taxed for domestic income "there", wherever that is.